# Custom wordpress HTTP redirects to HTTPS breaks website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have added extra rules in my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^/articles/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?name=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(articles/)(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?name=$2 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I have two conditions which seems to work:

- `http://example.com/this-is-old-url/` meets the first rewrite rule
- `http://example.com/articles/this-is-old-url/` meets the second rule

But the problem is that after these rules are added my website is starting to make redirects everywhere. For example, I can't access my domain `https://example.com` which changes to `https://example.com/index.php?name=`. All my website links breaks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just make a specific rule for your `this-is-old-url`. All non `atricles` URLs match the first rule as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule !^/articles/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?name=$1 [L,R=301]
> RewriteRule ^(articles/)(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?name=$2 [L,R=301]
> ```

The first rule matches *everything*, since the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in an `.htaccess` context never starts with a slash (you appear to have recognised this in your second rule). You also can't have capturing groups in negated *patterns* - by definition, a negated pattern doesn't actually match anything.

And the second rule executes unconditionally, for both HTTP and HTTPS, since `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. (But these two rules can be combined into one anyway.)

To externally "redirect" (as per your example) a URL of the form `http://example.com/this-is-old-url/` (or `http://example.com/articles/this-is-old-url/`) to `https://example.com/index.php?name=this-is-old-url` then you can do the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(?:articles/)?([\w-]+/)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?name=$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:** the regex now includes `-` (hyphens) and trailing slash. Note that the trailing slash is included as part of the capturing group. So, it redirects to `/index.php?name=this-is-old-url/` (with the trailing slash).

The subpattern `(?:articles/)?` is optional and non-capturing. So, this one rule matches both your example URLs.

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required. And neither is the `RewriteEngine` directive, since you presumably already have that in the WordPress code block that follows.

You don't necessarily need to expose the `index.php`, you could redirect to `/?name=...` instead, assuming the `DirectoryIndex` is set correctly.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. (Preferably test first with 302 - temporary - redirects.)

> I can't access my domain `https://example.com` which changes to `https://example.com/index.php?name=`.

That couldn't have happened with your existing rules, only if you'd requested `http://example.com` (note HTTP, not HTTPS).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I  have tried to test your added a new rule but I think is not working. Check this link [link](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=f19983d5-5bee-5e32-abac-df3eb89f06e1) . Actually I changed my rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*[/])?(.*/)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?name=$2 [L,R=301]` and I think it works, but problem I saw if i type https://example.com/wp-admin (not adding last /) I get somehow redirect even in https.

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed the hyphen (`-`) and trailing slash from the regex! I've updated my answer to include this. Not sure what you mean by your last sentence... the URL you posted already appears to be HTTPS (so these rules don't apply)? But `/wp-admin` is usually a physical directory, so mod_dir will automatically append the trailing slash via a 301-redirect if omitted. 301 redirects are naturally cached by the browser.

Comment: i will change my regex to yours because it looks more understandable and when I test with wp-admin, I accidentally wrote http, not https :) Thank you for your time and answer!